# How do I replace '\\' with '\'?

Tags: substitute

Tried

```
:s/\\\/\\/g
```

but VIM will search for `\\/\` instead.

So is there any way I can do this in Vim?

Comment: :%s/\\\\/\\/g double them up, eh?

Comment: When working with ``\`` or ``/``, I often use ``#`` as a delimiter for the substitute command because this is more easy to grasp visually (I feel), i.e. ``:s#\\\\#\\#g``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `s/\\\/\\/`:

1. the first `\` escapes the second `\`;
2. the second `\` is escaped, so it's no longer special; and
3. the third `\` isn't escaped, so it escapes the `/` after it.

So you need to escape the third `\` like the second was:

```
:s/\\\\/\\/g
```

Comment: thanks!! It worked.
but in '\\\\/', why the 4th '\' isn't escaped by the 1st '\' like the 2nd and the 3rd one?
in vim, how many character will be escaped by '\' exactly?

Comment: Usually, `\ ` escapes the next character, unless it is itself escaped by a `\ `. There are a lot of exceptions. See [`:h pattern-atoms`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern-atoms) for some of those

Comment: @TeddyC The 3rd `\ ` *isn't* escaped by the 1st. The 2nd is escaped by the 1st and the 4th is escaped by the 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

```
:1,$:s/\\\\/\\/g
```

1 means the first line and $ means till the last one.
each `\\` means `\`, and `\/` removes the `/` as divider, here you have your syntax error.

Comment: `:%s/from/to/g` may be better. % means all lines in the file

Comment: What OP posted isn't a syntax error though. `:s/\\\/\\/g` uses ``\\\/\\`` as the pattern and `g` as the replacement. (A trailing `/` is implied.)

Comment: @muru I thought that the trailing / was mandatory.